# mount command hangs when share is unavailable

Tags: mount, pam, smb, timeout

So we are using a combination of `samba`, `winbind` and `pam_mount` to authenticate users from AD and mount network share individually and everything works fine except for when a share is unavailable.

In that situation, the login process hangs for 20 minutes due to a 20 minute soft timeout of the `/bin/mount` call.

The mount command exits with the following error:

```
(mount.c:76): mount error(11): Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: This is a long standing issue / bug . See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/528314 and http://serverfault.com/questions/622238/linux-cifs-samba-mount-hangs-for-several-minutes